# automated screenshots of React application with PhantomJs/Webshot (or other)

Tags: meteor, reactjs, phantomjs

*Given you have a ReactJS web application

And want to take scripted snapshots of it.

How do you do it? What's your method?*

**What I've attempted:**

I have a React app with the stack managed by the Meteor frameworkwebpack.

I've attempted to use [WebShot][1] (via [bryanmorgan:webshot meteor smart package][2] which works great...outside of react components.

When react components are involved it seems to fail silently--plain HTML will be captured, but components are missed. (I've attempted page delays, and also triggered the snapshot on a onLoadFinished callback, none of which work.)

**Request**
Any suggestions on making this work?
Otherwise,
I've lost enough time on it, I'm perfectly happy to use a different strategy.

Comment: Not enough street cred to post more links, but here's some additional refs:
[Possible lead for workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/347) , 
[Long-standing WebShot issue](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot/issues/81)

Comment: May we have a look at a site sample, code sample, error logs?